# Changing URL format in craft commerce products error 502

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-craftcommerce2

I have more than 150k products on craft commerce, and i need to do some changes in the URL format, but when i click save, the server returns a 502 error.

I think that is because craft is trying yo re-generate every url in the 150k products.  do you have any idea  how to resolve this issue?

Comment: When does the 502 (bad gateway) error arisen (immediately/after x seconds) ? Do you get a chance to look at the job queue in the control panel before the error happens?

I have done url schema changes with a basic craft installation with about 60k entries. Changeing the urls was correctly done using the job queue. So the "problem" was rather how long it took the server to complete all jobs and not the webserver being "overloaded".

Jalens Queue Manager plugin might give you more insights - provided the task gets deployed to the queue at all: https://plugins.craftcms.com/queue-manager

Comment: The error happens after 30-60 seconds, and i dont have pending jobs in queue